# Can I store information from Google API in database?

Tags: php, mysql, google-api

Im making a website where it has a user registration. What I was going to do is when a user logs in with Google, it stores their details (ID, email, name, picture and G+ link) in a local database.   Then every time the user connects to the website, it checks to see if the users ID is in the local database.  If it is, they are logged in and can access all their details and the documents etc they have uploaded.
If they're not, they can login.

Am I allowed to do this, or do I somehow have to authenticate the user on every page they visit and then find a way to link this to my local database?

Comment: I don't think you can't. There's a reason why the data users are sharing is called "public". It's the same with Facebook or Twitter or any other OAuth (or similar) data provider. Whenever you say that your name is John Doe, it means that anyone with access to the service provider will be able to see that. If you as a user don't want anyone to know about it, you simply click Cancel in the OAuth dialogue. (How do you add new lines on SO?)

Comment: Yes, however the login prompt from Google shows what I am requesting access too:
XXXXXX is requesting permission to:
View basic information about your account
View your name, public profile URL and photo. View your gender and date of birth. View your country, language and time zone.
View your email address
View the email address associated with your account
Perform these operations when I'm not using the application

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do not think you are allowed to store API information in your own database. On top of that, why would you go to such lengths to allow users to log in/access their documents. If you want to use their google info as login credentials all you have to do is instead of checking against your database, make an cURL call to google's API and see if they return you a user. If so, create a session and allow the user to log in.

Comment: Basically my database contains 5 fields as mentioned in my question.  If I didnt use Google, i'd be asking them to fill out that information anyway, so all im doing is using Google to populate the data.

When the user logs into the site, they have the ability to upload files, comment etc, so I would need a way to query this and if I cant query against my database then I dont see how I can do it?

I imagine the site will become quite heavy on traffic, so if its calling the Google API for every page load, I will soon hit the 10,000 per month API call limit..

Comment: Keep the uploaded documents, etc in your database. But google's data is already available and there is no need to store it yourself. (its probably not legal). Better would be to make a google api call when they log in, and have google return you the user information you'd pull from your database and stick it in a session at login.

Comment: Guess that would be a way to do it.  However, how do I identify which database entries are for the user.  The only unique field I can see Google uses is the User ID which is a string of numbers, however if Im not allowed to keep that in the database then I dont see how I can do it.  The whole system im trying to implement is pretty much EXACTLY the same as how StackOverflow does it

Comment: @Greg Hesp Use their google Id as a primary key in your database. That isn't bad, as long as it's just a key and it pertains to different records then the google ones. An exact copy of API data (or cache of it) isn't allowed. Their Id you can just stick in the session and viola you have your user and their unique info without all the hassle of a user table in your database!

Comment: @Greg Hesp And if keeping their key doesn't sound like something you want to do, you could easily generate your own keys based on some of the returned data from the API call. (Couple email charactors, hash of google's id, and put the whole thing into MD5 or SHA1 for instance)

Answer (score 0):

Using google plus client side flow and adding the HTML-based sign-in button. Call userid via ajax and then insert the resp.id into a session. The sessionid is stored in a database.

However when closing the browser and login again a whole new session starts and there's no access to any of the previous uploaded documents.